# Can you create several projective textures in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, 3d

Is it possible to create multiple projective textures in open gl? I've tried the demo at http://www.sgi.com/products/software/opengl/examples/glut/advanced/ (projtest.c) but I don't know whether it would be extensible to several instances. All demos I've seen use only one projective texture.

Comment: if you use shaders (in GLSL for instance) then you can do as many projective textures as you can... but when using a fixed pipeline you are a bit limited and the code could be quite complicated. I hope you use shaders only. Here is some good info about that: http://www.ozone3d.net/tutorials/glsl_texturing.php

Comment: @fen, I am now using shaders, it works fine with a single texture, but how do I extend this to a second texture, projected from a different position and with different orientation? I can't apply more than a single shader to any object!

Comment: probably you will have to send several different matrices for each projection and then you will be able to have multiple views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use as many projective textures as you like.

Comment: also using the method on the demo I posted? I know there are several methods, some of them including shaders.

Comment: Why do you think this method does _not_?

Comment: I saw the code and I guess I got scared by the EYE PLANE and texture generation bits. I thought it was something "to be defined once". Guess I was wrong.

Comment: Okay so now I tried to use several textures over the same object with the method I posted, but when I try to draw my object, I can only use one of them since I have to call glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID); before drawing the object, and only one texture can be bound. How would you solve this, then?